# Infinite Loop in Java 2d array program

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, infinite

The program is supposed to end and give the amount of correct answers once the last question is answered. Instead the program goes back to the initial question in the loop. 
"What is the capital of Alabama"

```
package exercise09_17;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exercise09_17 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n"); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        String [][] grid = {
                {"Alabama", "California", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
                "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Kansas", "Lousiana", "Maryland", "New Mexico", "Oregon",
                "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "Texas", "Utah", "Virgina",
                "West Virginia"},
                {"Montgomery", "Sacramento", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta",
                "Honolulu", "Boise", "Topeka", "Baton Rouge", "Annapolis", "San Jose", "Salem",
                "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Richmond",
                "Charleston"}};

        for(int i = 0; i< grid.length; i++){

            for(int k = 0; k < grid[i].length; k++ ){
                System.out.println("What is the capital of " + grid[0][k] + "?");
                String capital = input.next();
                String answer = grid[1][k];


                if(capital.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
                correctAnswer ++;   
                System.out.println("Your answer is correct");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("The correct answer should be " + answer);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The correct count is " + correctAnswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not infinite.  It's merely repeating itself because of the nesting of the loops.

Comment: The statement that prints the count is inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not infinite.  It just goes twice:

```
for(int i = 0; i< grid.length; i++){
```

There's no need for this `i` variable here, and hence the entire outer-loop as well, since you use both sub-arrays, `grid[0]` and `grid[1]` on the first go-through

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extraneous `for loop`:

```
public class exercise09_17 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n"); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        String [][] grid = {
                {"Alabama", "California", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
                "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Kansas", "Lousiana", "Maryland", "New Mexico", "Oregon",
                "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "Texas", "Utah", "Virgina",
                "West Virginia"},
                {"Montgomery", "Sacramento", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta",
                "Honolulu", "Boise", "Topeka", "Baton Rouge", "Annapolis", "San Jose", "Salem",
                "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Richmond",
                "Charleston"}};



        for(int k = 0; k < grid[0].length; k++ ){
            System.out.println("What is the capital of " + grid[0][k] + "?");
            String capital = input.next();
            String answer = grid[1][k];


            if(capital.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
                correctAnswer ++;   
                System.out.println("Your answer is correct");
            } else
                System.out.println("The correct answer should be " + answer);
        }

        System.out.println("The correct count is " + correctAnswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet won't compile because there is no `i` variable, the for loop should have `k < grid[0].length`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
System.out.println("What is the capital of " + grid[0][k] + "?");
```

to

```
System.out.println("What is the capital of " + grid[i][k] + "?");
```

Since you are using `grid[0][k]` after going through all k iterations it will come back for another k iteration on same `i=0` till  `i<grid.length`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an infinite loop, but you will repeat the process as many times as the grid length. Basically, you do not need the outer for loop. Remove the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
```

and instead of

```
for(int k = 0; k < grid[i].length; k++ ){
```

change to

```
for(int k = 0; k < grid[0].length; k++ ){
```